# FileReader class in C#

Tags: c#, .net, filereader

I am looking for fast class for to work with text files and comfortable reading different object (methods like NextInt32, NextDouble, NextLine, etc). Can you advice me something?

**Edit:** BinaryReader is bad class in my case. Format of my data is not binary. I have file like

```
1 2 3
FirstToken NextToken
1.23 2,34
```

And I want read this file with code like:

```
int a = FileReader.NextInt32();
int b = FileReader.NextInt32();
int c = FileReader.NextInt32();
int d = FileReader.NextString();
int e = FileReader.NextString();
int f = FileReader.NextDouble();
int g = FileReader.NextDouble();
```

**Edit2:** I am looking for analog Scanner from Java

Comment: From the example I tkae it: All whitespace (space, newline etc) is separator, and you know the order in which data (the types) will appear. Can you confirm this?

Comment: By the way, `2,34` in your sample input should be treated as a single decimal number `2.24` (i.e. you want to handle both period and comma as decimal point), or as two integers `2` and `24`, or as string `"2,24"`? If you want both kinds of decimal separators, have you considered the fact that other locales may use other characters for this purpose (neither comma nor period)?

Comment: @Pavel Minaev, In ideal case params of constructor contains set of token separators and set of decimals separators. "2.24" we can read as string and can read as double (both way are valid)

Comment: Passing decimal separators specifically sounds like a bad idea, because that would necessitate custom number parsing code. How about passing a `CultureInfo` instead?

Comment: @Pavel Minaev: I think, It is good idea

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm going to add this as a separate answer because it's quite distinct from the answer I already gave. Here's how you could start creating your own Scanner class:

```
class Scanner : System.IO.StringReader
{
  string currentWord;

  public Scanner(string source) : base(source)
  {
     readNextWord();
  }

  private void ReadNextWord()
  {
     System.Text.StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
     char nextChar;
     int next;
     do
     {
        next = this.Read();
        if (next < 0)
           break;
        nextChar = (char)next;
        if (char.IsWhiteSpace(nextChar))
           break;
        sb.Append(nextChar);
     } while (true);
     while((this.Peek() >= 0) && (char.IsWhiteSpace((char)this.Peek())))
        this.Read();
     if (sb.Length > 0)
        currentWord = sb.ToString();
     else
        currentWord = null;
  }

  public bool HasNextInt()
  {
     if (currentWord == null)
        return false;
     int dummy;
     return int.TryParse(currentWord, out dummy);
  }

  public int NextInt()
  {
     try
     {
        return int.Parse(currentWord);
     }
     finally
     {
        readNextWord();
     }
  }

  public bool HasNextDouble()
  {
     if (currentWord == null)
        return false;
     double dummy;
     return double.TryParse(currentWord, out dummy);
  }

  public double NextDouble()
  {
     try
     {
        return double.Parse(currentWord);
     }
     finally
     {
        readNextWord();
     }
  }

  public bool HasNext()
  {
     return currentWord != null;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

I believe this extension method for `TextReader` would do the trick:

```
public static class TextReaderTokenizer
{
    // Adjust as needed. -1 is EOF.
    private static int[] whitespace = { -1, ' ', '\r' , '\n', '\t' };

    public static T ReadToken<T>(this TextReader reader)
    {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        while (Array.IndexOf(whitespace, reader.Peek()) < 0)
        {
            sb.Append((char)reader.Read());
        }
        return (T)Convert.ChangeType(sb.ToString(), typeof(T));
    }    
}
```

It can be used thus:

```
TextReader reader = File.OpenText("foo.txt");
int n = reader.ReadToken<int>();
string s = reader.ReadToken<string>();
```

**[EDIT]** As requested in question comments, here's an instance wrapper version of the above that is parametrized with delimiters and `CultureInfo`:

```
public class TextTokenizer
{
    private TextReader reader;
    private Predicate<char> isDelim;
    private CultureInfo cultureInfo;

    public TextTokenizer(TextReader reader, Predicate<char> isDelim, CultureInfo cultureInfo)
    {
        this.reader = reader;
        this.isDelim = isDelim;
        this.cultureInfo = cultureInfo;
    }

    public TextTokenizer(TextReader reader, char[] delims, CultureInfo cultureInfo)
    {
        this.reader = reader;
        this.isDelim = c => Array.IndexOf(delims, c) >= 0;
        this.cultureInfo = cultureInfo;
    }

    public TextReader BaseReader
    {
        get { return reader; }
    }

    public T ReadToken<T>()
    {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        while (true)
        {
            int c = reader.Peek();
            if (c < 0 || isDelim((char)c))
            {
                break;
            }
            sb.Append((char)reader.Read());
        }
        return (T)Convert.ChangeType(sb.ToString(), typeof(T));
    }    
}
```

Sample usage:

```
TextReader reader = File.OpenText("foo.txt");
TextTokenizer tokenizer = new TextTokenizer(
    reader,
    new[] { ' ', '\r', '\n', '\t' },
    CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
int n = tokenizer.ReadToken<int>();
string s = tokenizer.ReadToken<string>();
```

Answer (score 4):

You should define *exactly* what your file format is meant to look like. How would you represent a string with a space in it? What determines where the line terminators go?

In general you can use `TextReader` and its `ReadLine` method, followed by `double.TryParse`, `int.TryParse` etc - but you'll need to pin the format down more first.

Comment: To add to this, one could add a decorator class for `TextReader` to provide convenience `ReadInt32` etc methods; or extension methods on `TextReader` itself. I'm not aware of any such stock classes, however.

Comment: @DreamWalker: the reason why there isn't any standard class for this is that there's a multitude of slightly different text-based formats with no clear standard: whitespace or commas for separators; quoted strings optional/required/not supported; etc. The most common one is CSV (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values), and even then there are variations; but at least if you had CSV, there are quite a few premade parsers out there. If you want something different, you will most likely have to write it yourself.

Comment: @Pavel Minaev: I was hoping that there is already written class. It is not necessarily standart class. It can be class from some open-source framework or something like it

Answer (score 2):

Have you checked out the BinaryReader class?  Yes it's a text file but there is nothing stopping you from treating it as binary data and hence using BinaryReader.  It has all of the methods that you are looking for with the exception of ReadLine.  However it wouldn't be too difficult to implement that method on top of BinaryReader.

Comment: Agreed, except that implementing ReadLine on top of `BinaryReader` *would* be some task, if you design it to handle arbitrary encodings and not interrupt the reading of binary data.

Comment: @Henk, yes.  It just sees a stream of bytes.  As long as the encoding is correct it will read them.

Comment: @Noldorin, yeah making it Encoding agnostic would be a bit tricky.

Comment: @JaredPar: Using BinaryReader.ReadDouble won't read *text* and parse it though. It will treat that text as bytes, which isn't the idea.

Comment: Jaredpar, that is not what I would call a __Text__ file. The BinaryReader is more usefull, but only if the OP owns the format.

Answer (score 1):

If you *do* need text files (ie UTF-8 or ASCII encoding) then the binary writer will not work.

You can use the **`TextReader`**, but unlike the `BinaryReader` and the `TextWriter` it does not support any types other than Line and `char`. You will have to define what separators are allowed and parse the Line base data yourself.

Comment: I think, than string.Split() is very slow method. I need speed

Answer (score 0):

The **System.IO.BinaryReader** class is what you need.

Example of implementation of a **ReadLine** method:

```
public static class Extensions
{
    public static String ReadLine(this BinaryReader binaryReader)
    {
        var bytes = new List<Byte>();
        byte temp;

        while ((temp = (byte)binaryReader.Read()) < 10)
            bytes.Add(temp);

        return Encoding.Default.GetString(bytes.ToArray());
    }
}
```

Example for using this class:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Security.Permissions;

class Test
{
    static void Main()
    {
        // Load application settings.
        AppSettings appSettings = new AppSettings();
        Console.WriteLine("App settings:\nAspect Ratio: {0}, " +
            "Lookup directory: {1},\nAuto save time: {2} minutes, " +
            "Show status bar: {3}\n",
            new Object[4]{appSettings.AspectRatio.ToString(),
            appSettings.LookupDir, appSettings.AutoSaveTime.ToString(),
            appSettings.ShowStatusBar.ToString()});

        // Change the settings.
        appSettings.AspectRatio   = 1.250F;
        appSettings.LookupDir     = @"C:\Temp";
        appSettings.AutoSaveTime  = 10;
        appSettings.ShowStatusBar = true;

        // Save the new settings.
        appSettings.Close();
    }
}

// Store and retrieve application settings.
class AppSettings
{
    const string fileName = "AppSettings#@@#.dat";
    float  aspectRatio;
    string lookupDir;
    int    autoSaveTime;
    bool   showStatusBar;

    public float AspectRatio
    {
        get{ return aspectRatio; }
        set{ aspectRatio = value; }
    }

    public string LookupDir
    {
        get{ return lookupDir; }
        set{ lookupDir = value; }
    }

    public int AutoSaveTime
    {
        get{ return autoSaveTime; }
        set{ autoSaveTime = value; }
    }

    public bool ShowStatusBar
    {
        get{ return showStatusBar; }
        set{ showStatusBar = value; }
    }

    public AppSettings()
    {
        // Create default application settings.
        aspectRatio   = 1.3333F;
        lookupDir     = @"C:\AppDirectory";
        autoSaveTime  = 30;
        showStatusBar = false;

        if(File.Exists(fileName))
        {
            BinaryReader binReader =
                new BinaryReader(File.Open(fileName, FileMode.Open));
            try
            {
                // If the file is not empty,
                // read the application settings.
                // First read 4 bytes into a buffer to
                // determine if the file is empty.
                byte[] testArray = new byte[3];
                int count = binReader.Read(testArray, 0, 3);

                if (count != 0)
                {
                    // Reset the position in the stream to zero.
                    binReader.BaseStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);

                    aspectRatio   = binReader.ReadSingle();
                    lookupDir     = binReader.ReadString();
                    autoSaveTime  = binReader.ReadInt32();
                    showStatusBar = binReader.ReadBoolean();
                }
            }

            // If the end of the stream is reached before reading
            // the four data values, ignore the error and use the
            // default settings for the remaining values.
            catch(EndOfStreamException e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("{0} caught and ignored. " +
                    "Using default values.", e.GetType().Name);
            }
            finally
            {
                binReader.Close();
            }
        }

    }

    // Create a file and store the application settings.
    public void Close()
    {
        using(BinaryWriter binWriter =
            new BinaryWriter(File.Open(fileName, FileMode.Create)))
        {
            binWriter.Write(aspectRatio);
            binWriter.Write(lookupDir);
            binWriter.Write(autoSaveTime);
            binWriter.Write(showStatusBar);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: That's a *very* strange implementation of ReadLine, as well as using the default encoding rather than the encoding of the binary reader. How would you expect it to ever return any printable text?

Comment: Additionally - *Binary*Reader isn't appropriate for *text* files.

Answer (score 0):

You can probably use the [System.IO.File](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.aspx) Class to read the file and [System.Convert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.convert%28VS.71%29.aspx) to parse the strings you read from the file.

```
string line = String.Empty;
while( (line = file.ReadLine()).IsNullOrEmpty() == false )
{
   TYPE value = Convert.ToTYPE( line );
}
```

Where `TYPE` is whatever type you're dealing with at that particular line / file.

If there are multiple values on one line you could do a split and read the individual values e.g.

```
string[] parts = line.Split(' ');
if( parts.Length > 1 )
{
   foreach( string item in parts )
   {
      TYPE value = Convert.ToTYPE( item );
   }
}
else
{
   // Use the code from before
}
```

Comment: This will treat each line as a single value. He wants a _single_ line `foo 123 bar` to be treated as 3 distinct values.

Comment: @Pavel Minaev Added support for that, thanx for the suggestion